# XSLT inject variable xml file into existing xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon, inject

Been working a while now with XSLT transformation with the Saxon processor. Mostly I can find my answers and build what I want but this time...

I need to add data from other XML files to an existing XML, the data that has to be inserted is defined by a node in the base-xml.

Base XML:

```
<gang_job version="1.2"
          gang_job_name="Layout"
          gang_job_id="Automatic gang job"
          gang_job_customer_id="-1"
          gang_job_customer_name="unnamed">
   <mso_quality_job usage="85" total_cost="1000"/>
   <mso_plate width="530"
              height="459"
         <mso_quality_plate>
         <volume_use result="85.45333054436504"
                     volume_low="0"
                     volume_high="2147483647"/>
         <multiple1up result="23.52227020526318"
                      active="false"
                      delivery_low="0"
                      delivery_high="2147483647"/>
      </mso_quality_plate>
      <gang_part part_id="MGD9E97H5D"
                 part_object="Block 1"
      </gang_part>
      <gang_part part_name="Ganging / HF_ganging"
                 part_id="MG3BE3D10G"
                 part_object="Block 1"
      </gang_part>
   </mso_plate>
</gang_job>
```

The inserted XML files are named just as the gang_job/mso_plate/gang_part/@part_id, the nodes after /orderMetadata/items/item have to be injected.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orderMetadata>
  <orderId>MGD9E97H5D</orderId>
   <items>
    <item>
      <itemId>MGD9E97H5D</itemId>
      <isTestItem>false</isTestItem>    
      <sku>SKU</sku>
      <orderId>1337</orderId>         
      <quantity>500</quantity>
      <name>name</name>
      <description>Description</description>
      <document>URL to document</document>
      <productManufacturingData>
        <Material>Material</Material>
        <Format>Format</Format>
        <Finishing>Finishing</Finishing>
      </productManufacturingData>
      <deliveryDetails>    
        <deliveryDetail>
          <type>Standard</type>
          <quantity>500</quantity>
          <destinationAddress>
            <city>Amsterdam</city>
           </destinationAddress>
        </deliveryDetail>
      </deliveryDetails>
    </item>
  </items>  
</orderMetadata>
```

I was trying this but no result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="gang_job/mso_plate/gang_part">
    <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

            <xsl:variable name="Path">/Volumes/Directory/SubDirectory</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="Extension">.xml</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="FullPath" select="string(concat($docRoot,@part_id,$Extension))"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="document($FullPath)/orderMetadata/items/item">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Before that I tried it directly without the variables:

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('/Volumes/Directory/SubDirectory{@part_id}.xml')/orderMetadata/items/item">
```

Comment: If you want to copy nodes you can just use `xsl:copy-of` e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="document('foo.xml')/orderMetadata/items/item"/>`, there is no need to use `for-each` and nest `copy` and `apply-templates`. Other than that you will need to test yourself whether your path is correct, you can run Saxon (9) with the `-t` option to see which files it loads. Or at least show us exactly what "no result" means, whether Saxon gives any error or which output you get.

Comment: `for-each select="document('/Volumes/Directory/SubDirectory{@part_id}.xml')` would be wrong if you expect the `{@part_id}` to be executed, that doesn't work in a string literal of a `select` expression of a `for-each`.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. In your first fragment, there seems to be some muddle about variables `$docRoot` vs `$Path`. Either way, remember that document() expects a URI, not a filename. I would expect something like `"file:///Volumes/Directory/SubDirectoryMGD9E97H5D.xml"` (or is there another slash after "SubDirectory"?

Are you intending the URI to be absolute or relative?

I would change the stylesheet to use version="3.0" rather than "1.0", because that gives stricter checking and therefore better diagnostics.

In your second example (showing your first attempt) the use of curly braces inside a string literal is wishful thinking. You need to construct the URI using string concatenation. In XSLT 3.0 (with `expand-text="yes"`) you can use

```
<xsl:variable name="uri" as="xs:string">file:///Volumes/Directory/SubDirectory{$part_id}.xml</xsl:variable>
```

When you've got the URI right, using

```
<xsl:copy-of select="doc($uri)"/>
```

should be all that you need to do the inclusion.